# Find the density of states of a bouncing ball

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, phase-space, density-of-states

> Imagine a ball falling from a maximum height of $h$ and colliding with the ground at $z=0$. The ball only moves in the z-axis and the collisions are elastic. My job is to show that the density of states is $D_i(\epsilon)=\sqrt{\frac{8\epsilon)}{mg^2h^2}}$.

**My attempt**:
The total energy of the system at any given time (or its hamiltonian) is:

$$
H=mgz+\frac{p^2}{2m}
$$

Now, denoting (as convention from any statistical physics book I've seen) $\Omega (\epsilon)$ the number of microstates accessible to the system with energy between $\epsilon $ and $\epsilon +d\epsilon$, then one could write:

$$
\Omega(\epsilon)=D_1(\epsilon)d\epsilon
$$

Also, from what I gather, the phase space, in this case 2-dimensional, is to be divided in cells of area $dzdp$ or, for practical reasons (so as to have half a circunference for the phase space trajectory), $dz'dp'$ where $z'=\sqrt{mgz}$ and $p'=\frac{p}{\sqrt{2m}}$, and each cell represents a possible microstate of the system. So, the area between the energies of $\epsilon $ and $\epsilon +d\epsilon$ divided by $dz'dp'$ should solve this problem. However, when writing:

$$
\Omega (\epsilon)=\frac{\pi RdR}{dz'dp'}=\frac{\pi d\epsilon}{2\sqrt{\frac{mg}{z}}dz\frac{dp}{\sqrt{2m}}}
$$

I see no way of the getting to the correct expression. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The concept of density of states is only really useful when applied to a system with a huge number of degrees of freedom. It's not really meaningful to talk about the density of states of a single particle.

Comment: Yes, but the concept of density of states could be applied to any system so this exercise should be doable, right?

Comment: @tparker, this concept is really useful in statistical and condensed matter physics. The one-particle density of states is the main characteristic of quantum ideal gases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should notice that $h$ in $D(\epsilon)$ is the Planck constant, not a maximum height. The system under consideration has one degree of freedom. Its hamiltonian function has the form you've written. Its phase space is: $x\in(0,\infty)$, $p\in(-\infty,\infty)$. It is known in statistical mechanics, that for such a system the number of states with the energy less then $E$ in the quasiclassical limit is
$$
\Gamma(E) = \frac1h \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\! d p \int\limits_0^\infty\! dz\ \theta\left(E - \frac{p^2}{2m} - mgz\right) = \frac{4E^\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2m}}{3mgh}
$$
Hence, the density of states
$$
D(\epsilon) = \frac{d\,\Gamma}{d\,\epsilon}(\epsilon) = \sqrt{\frac{8\epsilon}{mg^2h^2}}.
$$

Comment: I understood most of your answer, but I got stuck at 4 things: i) Why do you divide by the planck constant? ii) What do you consider the quasiclassical limit? iii) Why do you consider that the system only has one degree of freedom when it has 2 distinct ways of acquiring energy (potential and kinetic) and iv) what was I getting wrong?

Comment: I shall try to answer. i), ii) The number of quantum states in the element of phase space $dxdp$ is equal to $dxdp/h$. In my opinion, it is a well known quasiclassical formula. iii) The number of degrees of freedom of a classical system is equal to the number of independent coordinates. In this example, there is only one coordinate $z$. The phase space dimension is twice the number of degrees of freedom. iv) I do not understand your arguments in the second part of the message.

Comment: @Bidon, The dimension of the Planck constant is equal to the dimension of $dxdp$. Hence the division by $h$ in the formula for the number of states.

Comment: but that means that any area, $A$, on the phase space divided by $h$ gives us the number of states accessible to the system with the energy limited by that area $A$. I used to think that $A$ was a mere number and a single cell of area $dxdp$ represented one state, hence doing $\frac{A}{dxdp}$ would give me a dimensionless quantity that represented the number of states within $A$, what is the motivation to define $\frac{dxdp}{h}$ as the number of states in a cell of phase space? is it a pure convenience of dimensions or is there a more deep meaning?

Comment: @Bidon, division by $h$ has physical meaning. For a free particle on a circle, possible values of momentum are $h n/L$, where $n$ is an integer and $L$ is a length of the circle. So the number of states with the momentum value lying in an interval of width $\Delta p$ is equal to $L\Delta p/h$. It's just a simple example, but the formula $dxdp/h$ is applicable in the general situation.